# Redirect specific endpoint, specific http method with nginx

Tags: nginx

I would like to redirect (or 404, whatever) ONLY a specific endpoint (let's say, `/my-path`) AND specific method (e.g. `POST`).
I want everything else not affected; that is, `POST /my-path` will go 404, but `GET /my-path` still works, and `POST /my-path/another-path` also works.

How can I achieve this with nginx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: use `$request_method`.

Example: make `POST` requests receive `404` but other methods can pass.

```
location /my-location {
    if ($request_method = POST) {
        return 404;  # or whatever special handling
    }
    # Normal case goes here
}
```